# Unity iOS gyroscope always returns constant value

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, gyroscope, core-motion

I'm reading the gyroscope on a Unity iPhone app but **however I move the phone it returns the same value** it returns is always the constant value of `(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.70711, -0.70711)`.

I'm reading it along the lines of this:

```cs
void Start()
{
    Input.gyro.enabled = true;
    Debug.Log("Using Gyro for player rotation.", this);
}

void Update()
{
    Debug.Assert(Input.gyro.enabled);
    Debug.Log($"Gyro: {Input.gyro.attitude}");
}
```

The same approach works in a separate Unity iOS app.

- My app also targets the Quest, and includes the Quest integration (this does not cause problems on the other iOS app).
- Unity 2022.2.19. iOS 16.5.1. iPhone 11.
- I have set a value for "Privacy - Motion Usage Description" in `Info.plist`.
- The gyro outputs data correctly when I test it in the Editor using Unity Remote 5. (This also confirms the gyro works on my phone.)
- I have tested on an iPad Air 3 with the same results

Any idea what's going on?